# I am calculating balance qty from total qty and invoice qty. Each time it is calculating qty from same total qty but not from remaining total qty

Tags: sql, technical-indicator

If I have total qty = 100.
and it has been shipped in 4 phases line 40, 10, 25, 25 that equals to 100.
when I am running this query:

```
SELECT pl.quantity, pr.invoiceqty, (pl.quantity - pr.invoiceqty)balance 
FROM purchaseorderline pl, replenishmentrequisition pr
```

I am getting result like this :

| --total qty-- | --invoice qty-- | --balance qty-- |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 40 | 60 |
| 100 | 10 | 90 |
| 100 | 25 | 75 |
| 100 | 25 | 70 |

The result I want :

| --total qty-- | --invoice qty-- | --balance qty-- |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 40 | 60 |
| 60 | 10 | 50 |
| 50 | 25 | 25 |
| 25 | 25 | 00 |

Can someone help me with this situation.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Version 21.4.1.349

Comment: So, it's not MySQL? A quick search on that version numbering seems to point to Oracle db instead.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), p.p. 5 and 3.

Comment: Tags spam removed. Add one tag which matches your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your query to looks like :

```
SET @totalQty = -1;
SELECT 
  IF(@totalQty<0, pl.quantity, @totalQty) AS totalQty, 
  pr.invoiceqty, 
  @totalQty:=(@totalQty - pr.invoiceqty) AS balance 
FROM 
  purchaseorderline pl, replenishmentrequisition pr
```

Comment: Sorry but I am getting this error while running query.

Comment: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=:=;ANTITY, 
  @totalQty;<=, DRIVER=4.13.127

Comment: This query code for MySql, if you are using another sql server then you will need to modify it to be suitable for your server.